# Davening Mincha with their Mariv

Tags: shemoneh-esrei, tzibur-community, minyan, maariv, mincha-afternoon-prayer

If one needs to daven mincha and the only minyan that is close by is davening an early maariv can one daven their mincha shmoneh esri with their maariv shmoneh esri and then daven maariv with a different minyan later? I remember seeing  this idea somewhere (sources please).

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate...

Comment: @SethJ please find it and I will delete it.

Comment: I'm lookin' but I can't find it. Maybe it's not.

Comment: @sam even if it is a dupe, you don't need to delete just close. dupes can be useful as signposts to the main q.

Comment: Can this question be generalized to "Can I still accomplish Tefillah beTzibbur if I'm praying a different prayer than the rest of the Tzibbur?" or is there something about Mincha/Maariv that I'm missing?

Comment: @DoubleAA I was thinking that mariv is a new day as opposed to shachris to mincha ,but I guess it could be.

Comment: @sam If you're not talking about Erev Shabbat or Yom Tov than I bet it doesn't make a difference. Either way I recommend asking the general version first, and after you see the answers see if there is more to ask. Also Shacharit to Mussaf is much more likely than Shacharit to Mincha :)

Comment: True,I was thinking mincha and mariv because that is the more common case,and this has happened to me, wasn't sure what to do.

Comment: @sam Sorry to press, I'm just not clear what you decided: did you want to edit to the more general case or leave it and see if anyone discusses your case?

Answer (score 1):

The Shaar Hatziyon ([591:13](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49628&st=&pgnum=132&hilite=)) writes that if one is alone on Rosh Hashanah, one should try to daven at the same time as the tzibbur, and davening shacharis when they're doing mussaf isn't good enough.

Perhaps one can derive from here that tefillah betzibur must involve the individual and the congregation reciting the same tefillah.

Comment: I seem to recall a similar point made in a story about R Chaim of Brisk